# ERROR: No matching distribution found for transformers==4.20.1

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I am trying to install this specific version of transformers but I get the error:

```
pip3 install transformers==4.20.1

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement transformers==4.20.1 
from versions: 0.1, 2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.3.0, 2.4.0, 2.4.1,
2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.6.0, 2.7.0, 2.8.0, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.10.0, 2.11.0, 3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 
3.1.0, 3.2.0, 3.3.0, 3.3.1, 3.4.0, 3.5.0, 3.5.1, 4.0.0rc1, 4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.1.0, 
4.1.1, 4.2.0, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.3.0rc1, 4.3.0, 4.3.1, 4.3.2, 4.3.3, 4.4.0, 4.4.1, 
4.4.2, 4.5.0, 4.5.1, 4.6.0, 4.6.1, 4.7.0, 4.8.0, 4.8.1, 4.8.2, 4.9.0, 4.9.1, 4.9.2, 
4.10.0, 4.10.1, 4.10.2, 4.10.3, 4.11.0, 4.11.1, 4.11.2, 4.11.3, 4.12.0, 4.12.1, 
4.12.2, 4.12.3, 4.12.4, 4.12.5, 4.13.0, 4.14.0, 4.14.1, 4.15.0, 4.16.0, 4.16.1, 
4.16.2, 4.17.0, 4.18.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for transformers==4.20.1
```

I know the version exists since I have it installed on my local machine. I installing the package on an ubuntu remote machine. The Python version is 3.6.9. How can I get the version I need if it's saying that it doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 4.20.1 build does not support Python prior to 3.7.  You'll either need to pick an earlier version or upgrade your Python.

Answer (score 1):

You need Python >=3.7. You might also want to upgrade pip:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

https://pypi.org/project/transformers/4.20.0/